# Jquery thinks my <g> element is visible, even when display is set to none and/or visibility is set to hidden

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, display

Please take a look at the example I've created below.
When you click the button, the `<g>` is toggled and the green dot gets displayed or hidden.

Oddly though, the `is(':visible')` is ALWAYS returning true, even when the `visibility` is set to `hidden`.

Why is this happening?

```js
console.log('Jquery running...')

$("button").click( () => {
  var prev = $("g").attr('visibility');
  if (prev === 'hidden') {
$('g').attr('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
$('g').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
  }

  console.log('element is visible:', el.is(':visible'));
});

var el = $('g');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My Example</p>

<svg width="20" height="30">

<g>
<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
</g>
</svg>

<button> Toggle Dot </button>
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried setting `display` to `none` earlier and it didn't work either

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'v updated the code to use `visibility`. same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate cases that warrant attention:

---

## `visibility: hidden`

Elements with `visibility: hidden` are, according to [the JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), still considered visible by the `:visible` selector:

> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered
> visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

---

## `display: none`

Elements with `display: none` don't consume space in the layout, so theoretically should not be selected by the `:visible` selector. When we look at the [JQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js) used to determine whether an element is visible or not, it bases itself on three values:

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) { 
        return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

At least in Chrome, `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` are undefined for SVG elements.

That leaves us with the client rects, and this is where the problem seems to lie, as there is still a client rect associated with the `g` element that has its `display` set to `none`:

```js
console.log('Jquery running...')

$('button').click(() => {
  var prev = $('g').css('display');
  if (prev === 'none') {
    $('g').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('g').css('display', 'none');
  }
  
  console.log(el[0].getClientRects().length); // 1
})

var el = $('g');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My Example</p>

<svg width="20" height="30">

<g>
<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
</g>
</svg>

<button> Toggle Dot </button>
```

---

Looks like a bug in Chrome, because it works correctly in Firefox. There does, however, seem to be [confusion](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#svg-layout-box) about what `getClientRects()` needs to return in case of inner SVG elements.

Answer (score 2):

Toggling visibility of the `circle` works

**Jquery source code:**

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

Here `offsetWidth, offsetHeight, getClientRects()` returns `null` for `g` element

```js
console.log('Jquery running...')

$("button").click(() => {
  el.toggle();

  console.log('element is visible:', el.is(':visible'));
});

var el = $('g circle');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My Example</p>

<svg width="20" height="30">

<g>
<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
</g>
</svg>

<button> Toggle Dot </button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan not sure why jquery uses offsetWidth & offsetHeight instead of visibility or display setting :(

Comment: @mplungjan Because in Chrome, a `g` element with `display:none` still has a client rect associated with it, while a `circle` element doesn't. It works correctly in Firefox, so looks like a bug in Chrome. See my answer for details.